# How to select a static value/string with SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I keep forgetting -

I am selecting into an output file with terminal MySQL sever operations - I need to create a delimiter between SELECT sets. How can I insert a "---"?

```
SELECT "---";
```

Doesn't work obviously.

Also is there a way to format output from MySQL commands?

Mine looks like a mess:

```
track_id    track_title track_num   album   genre   artist  length  track_rating
1   Siberia 1   1   1   1   00:04:29    5
2   Where the Fence is Low  2   1   1   1   00:03:24    5
3   Toes    3   1   1   1   00:03:19    5
4   Banner  4   1   1   1   00:03:37    5
5   Everybody Breaks a Glass    5   1   1   1   00:03:55    5
6   Heavy Rope  6   1   1   1   00:03:59    5
7   Timing Is Everything    7   1   1   1   00:03:16    5
8   Peace Sign  8   1   1   1   00:03:20    5
9   Flux and Flow   9   1   1   1   00:03:17    5
10  Fourth Dimension    10  1   1   1   00:03:27    5
11  Hollywood   1   2   3   3   00:04:13    5
12  In This Moment  2   2   3   3   00:04:31    5
13  Some Kind of Wonderful  3   2   3   3   00:03:04    5
14  End of May  4   2   3   3   00:03:53    5
15  Me and Mrs. Jones   5   2   3   3   00:03:43    5
16  Have not met you yet    6   2   3   3   00:05:20    5
17  Heartache Tonight   7   2   3   3   00:03:47    5
18  Best of Me  8   2   3   3   00:04:33    5
19  Swimming in Miami   1   4   1   4   00:04:56    5
20  Captains and Cruise Ships   2   4   1   4   00:03:29    5
```

Comment: Where are you trying to put this string literal? Between rowsets?  You can simply do `SELECT '---';` in MySQL, you aren't required to have a `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you state "doesn't work, obviously" should work fine in MySQL.

If you feel the need to have a FROM clause in the SQL statement, the docs state that you can use `FROM DUAL` as "dummy" table.

Answer (score 2):

It's

```
select '---' ...
```

Note the single quotes.

Comment: Hmmm... is MySQL that forgiving about quotes? Neither Oracle nor MSSQL would be...

Answer (score 0):

> I need to create a delimiter between SELECT sets. How can I insert a "---"?

So, you have more than one query and you want the output to have a row with `---`. IMO: Awful :)

You'll have to do this:

```
select field1, field2, field3, etc... from yourTable
union all
select '---', null, null, etc...
union all
select field1, field2, field3, etc... from anotherTable
```